# Upgrade OpenSSL version to 3.0.10 in Ubutnu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, openssl

We are facing issue while upgrading OpenSSL version from 3.0.2 to 3.0.10 on our Ubuntu 22.04 instance which hosted in AWS account, kindly provide us some documentation so that we can upgrade the OpenSSL version and remove the Vulnerabilities.

Thanks,
Abdussamee